# Which method gets called when multiple overloads are legal?

Tags: java, interface, parameters, multiple-inheritance

Say you have an Interface `A`, and an Interface `B`. Let's say the `Sprite` class implements both interfaces.

Say there's another class that has a method `foo(A object)`, and also has a method `foo(B object)`.

Do both get called when I pass an instance of `Sprite` to the method `foo()`? If not, which has precedence?

Comment: what do you mean "called"? What methods do these interfaces define?

Comment: you probably meant class "Sprite" implements both A and B interfaces, not inherits from both.

Comment: The interfaces can define any methods, I'm wondering what will happen when foo() is called via Sprite. Sorry for imprecision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With method *overloading* (as is in use here), the method to call is resolved at compile time, based on the (declared) type of the variable holding the `Sprite`.

Since the method call is ambiguous, this will fail to compile until you manually downcast the reference to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: I think this link goes into a little more detail:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.12.2.5

Comment: @johusman: to be precise: it goes into **all* the detail there is, by definition ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It's ambiguous. You'll need to cast to one of the interfaces.

Answer (score 3):

```
   interface A {}

   interface B {}

   class Sprite implements A,B {}

   class Test{
      void foo(A a){}
      void foo(B b){}

      void test(){
       Sprite s = new Sprite();
       foo(s); // <-- compile time error (The method foo(A) is ambiguous for the type Test)
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The general answer requires several pages to explain; see [the relevant section in the language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2).

In the specific case you present, it just won't compile.  But in other cases there are rules by which the compiler may prefer one overload to another and resolve the conflict.

The most important rule is that, in general, if one method is *more specific* than the others, that method is picked.  Method A is *more specific* than method B if all possible invocations of method A would also compile if calling method B.  This usually means that some of the formal parameter(s) of method A are subclassed from the corresponding formal parameter(s) in method B.  There are a few cases where this won't apply, such as when auto-boxing or other "method conversion" would be required to make an argument fit in the otherwise "more specific" case.  For specifics, see the spec.